# Grails validators don't work

Tags: grails

I'm hoping this just needs a new pair of eyes casting over it.

I have a school class

```
class School {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(maxLength:50,blank:false)
    }

    static hasMany = [pupils:Reviewer]

    String toString() {
        return name
    }
}
```

I have a School controller

```
class SchoolController {
    def scaffold = School
}
```

When I run the app and put a very long ( much longer than 50 than 50 char ) or even a blank name into my add school form, the constraints don't seem to be obeyed.

What am I missing?

Dave

Comment: Just for kicks and grins see if changing the name of the field 'name' to something else. not sure, but seems like I remember running into issues using that once.  If that doesn't work then sorry I wasted your time :)

Comment: Changed the name field to something else but had no effect. Looks like it's down to my usage of maxLength as opposed to maxSize that was the problem. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Grails Validation Reference](http://www.grails.org/Validation+Reference#maxLength) maxLength is deprecated..

Have you tried using maxSize instead?

Comment: That's done it thanks - at least it's limited the size of the input field to 50 characters. It seems that using maxLength not only doesn't work, it also stops any subsequent contraints from firing as well.

Thanks for your help